# graphQL schema for types that allow custom attributes

Tags: graphql, apollo

I just recently started exploring graphQL and I'm very excited about it but I wonder how it might work when the schema can change based on user actions. The types in our application can have user defined attributes and I've read that dynamic schemas can be complicated in graphQL. Is there a solution for this type of schema in graphQl/Apollo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL works well for APIs where the "shape" of the data is fairly well-defined.  For example, in the [GitHub GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/), Repositories have Refs (tags or branches) have GitObjects (commits or tags) which all have a fairly fixed set of attributes.  You wouldn't create a separate GraphQL field for each branch; instead you might look for

```graphql
query WhereIsMaster($name: String!, $owner: String!) {
  repository(name: $name, owner: $owner) {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/master") {
      nodes {
        target {
          oid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're designing your own schema, and you have a key/value-type storage, you'd have to write your own lookup for it

```graphql
type KeyValuePair implements Node {
  id: ID!
  key: String!
  value: String!
}
type Query {
  lookup(key: String!): KeyValuePair
}
type Mutation {
  insert(key: String!, value: String!): KeyValuePair!
}
```

If your data model is truly freeform (as a prominent example, MongoDB allows arbitrary JSON documents to be stored) then GraphQL isn't a great match for it.